# Dynamicly add html elements through ngFor in AngularJS

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I am new comer in Angular 5. I would like to get the html elements from `.ts` file and dynamically add them in html file through `ngFor`. I tried to do it using `[innerHtml]` but it is not working and return me `[object HTMLSelectElement]`. How can I solve this problem?

```
transferDataSuccess(event) {   

var dropHere = document.getElementById('dropHere')

var dropInSettings = document.getElementById('dropInSettings')

for (var key in this.transferData) {

  if (this.transferData[key].name == event.dragData.name) {

    this.receivedData.push({

      elem:this.transferData[key].element});

    }
  }
}


<div class="panel-heading" id="dropHere" *ngFor="let x of receivedData" [innerHTML] = "x.elem">
```

Comment: what is the type of `element` in the `transferData` object?

Comment: element is a string type. But I have tried to create Html Element in js and use it, but that did not help

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this can be as below:

let's say your options are coming dynamically from the service and you want to create `<option>` element dynamically.

A sample snippet to describe the functionality :

```
<select>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options;">
    <option [value]="option['value']">{{option['label']}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

If you already have the element in the component, you can access it using the ElementRef as below:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('element', this.el.nativeElement);
    this.el.nativeElement.getElementById('dropHere');
  }
}
```

If it not good practice to manipulate DOM from the component class.

I hope this help.